# attempt to index global 'playButton' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have just started a LUA a few weeks ago. I was able to create a simple character jumping with a score and then running this with the Corona Simulator. But I wanted to create a menu system so from main.lua which loads up menu.lua and from here it will go to Start (i.e. start the game i.e. to game.lua) and therefore I can play the game. But it doesn't appear. I have tried to add the eventListeners as shown below o

```
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen
        startButton:addEventListener( "tap", gotoGame )
        highScoresButton:addEventListener( "tap", gotoHighScores )

    end
end
```

Other than that I dont understand why the menu system won't go to Game.lua therefore I can play the game. Also I don't understand why there are errors when loading menu.lua I have used scenes and the composer management library and in theory it should work.

Image files are in one folder

**main.lua** File 1

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

-- Hide status bar
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- Seed the random number generator
math.randomseed( os.time() )

-- Go to the menu screen
composer.gotoScene("menu")
```

**Menu.lua** File 2

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Code outside of the scene event functions below will only be executed ONCE unless
-- the scene is removed entirely (not recycled) via "composer.removeScene()"
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local function gotoGame()
    composer.gotoScene( "game" )
end

local function gotoHighScores()
    composer.gotoScene( "highscores" )
end


-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event functions
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- create()
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared on screen

    local background = display.newImageRect( sceneGroup, "background.png", 800, 1400 )
    background.x = display.contentCenterX
    background.y = display.contentCenterY

    local title = display.newImageRect( sceneGroup, "title.png", 500, 80 )
    title.x = display.contentCenterX
    title.y = 200

    local startButton = display.newText( sceneGroup, "Start", display.contentCenterX, 700, native.systemFont, 44 )
    startButton:setFillColor( 0.82, 0.86, 1 )

    local highScoresButton = display.newText( sceneGroup, "High Scores", display.contentCenterX, 810, native.systemFont, 44 )
    highScoresButton:setFillColor( 0.75, 0.78, 1 )

    startButton:addEventListener( "tap", gotoGame )
    highScoresButton:addEventListener( "tap", gotoHighScores )
end


-- show()
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen
        startButton:addEventListener( "tap", gotoGame )
        highScoresButton:addEventListener( "tap", gotoHighScores )

    end
end


-- hide()
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs immediately after the scene goes entirely off screen

    end
end


-- destroy()
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs prior to the removal of scene's view

end


-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event function listeners
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

**game.lua** File 3

```
local composer = require("composer")

local scene = composer.newScene()
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
local physics = require "physics"





function updateScore()
    score=score+1
    scoreText.text = "Score: "..score
    scoreText.x, scoreText.y=80,40
end



function onTouch(event)
    if(event.phase=="began") then
        if(event.x<player.x) then
            player:setLinearVelocity(-30,-200)
            updateScore()
        else
            player:setLinearVelocity(30,-200)
            updateScore()
        end
    end
end


-- create()
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared
    physics.pause()
    score=0
    local scoreText
    local ground = display.newImage("ground.jpg")
    local player = display.newImage("player.png")


end

-- show()
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen
        physics.start()
        scoreText=display.newText("Score:0",0,0,native.systemFont,40)
        scoreText.x, scoreText.y=80,40

        ground.x=460
        ground.y=1300
        physics.addBody(ground, "static")


        player.x=360
        player.y=120

        physics.addBody(player)
        Runtime:addEventListener("touch", onTouch)
    end
end


-- hide()
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs immediately after the scene goes entirely off screen

    end
end


-- destroy()
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs prior to the removal of scene's view

end


-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event function listeners
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: Show all code for menu.lua and game.lua

Comment: the provided code does not index playButton. Usually error messages come with file names and lines.

Comment: This is all the code I have

Comment: [Lua*](http://lua.org/about.html#name)

Comment: `playButton` isn't defined anywhere, so I have no idea how you're getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the scene with

```
function scene:create( event )
```

You always want to insert the objects (locals) into the sceneGroup doing this

```
sceneGroup:insert( object )
sceneGroup:insert( object2 )
```

Also I have the doubt that the event listener goes with touch and not tap (by looking on the doumentation):

```
startButton:addEventListener( "touch", gotoGame )
highScoresButton:addEventListener( "touch", gotoHighScores )
```

Anyway I suggest you to visit the [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/): it covers everything and it's euxhastive.